# Merge node tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

As far as I can tell, we've got two tags for Node.js: [node.js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.js) and [nodejs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodejs).  Can we merge them to reduce confusion?

Answer (score 9):

There were only 5 [nodejs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) questions and they all actually referred to [node.js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.js) so I went ahead and create the synonym and merged the tags.

If any one tries to use [nodejs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) now it will automatically get converted to [node.js](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.js)